# An html symbol ruin elements text alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am using an HTML symbol for my pagination but it ruins the alignment with other elements:

```css
a{
  float:left;  
}
```

```html
<div dir='rtl'>
<a href='#'>&#10092;&#10092; text 1</a> 
<a href='#'>&#10092; text 2</a>
<a href='#'>  text 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: why using float to start with?

Comment: I was stupid, followed an example, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a line height to the `a` element.

I added `line-height:1`. Check the snippet

```css
a{
  float:left;
  line-height:1
}
```

```html
<div dir='rtl'>
<a href='#'>&#10092;&#10092; text 1</a> 
<a href='#'>&#10092; text 2</a>
<a href='#'>  text 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it drove me crazy with my tired mind!